# How to click the notification and jump back to iterm2 from apple script?

Tags: notifications, applescript

I have a script to notify me after a long running bash job finished in iterm2

```
on run argv
  tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
  if frontApp is not "iTerm2" then
      set notifTitle to item 1 of argv
      set notifBody to "succeded"
      set errorCode to item 2 of argv
      if errorCode is not "0"
        set notifBody to "failed with error code " & errorCode
      end if
      display notification notifBody with title notifTitle
    end if
  end tell
```

end run

The annoying part is when I click the notification, it opens up apple script editorr. The behavior I want to achieve is redirect me back to iterm2. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Have you tried adding, e.g. `activate application "iTerm2"` after the `display notification` _command_?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the response. But this is not what I want. I want to click the notification and get back to iTerm2, not activate it every time

Comment: First of all it's not clear how your code "opens up apple script editorr" in reference to "The annoying part is when I click the notification" and secondly you've not include enough details i.e., an example to reproduce the issue, so have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.  It's also not clear whether or not you're looking for a programatic way of clicking the notification or you want to manually dismiss, or you want iTerm to stay in the background or what, etc.

Comment: If you run `/usr/bin/osascript -e 'display notification "hello word" with title "Notification"` and then click on the notification you will see that it opens `ActionScript` app. I would also like to know how to set a handler on the click action